# PCF filtering on OpenGL

Tags: opengl, shadows, pcf

I'm reading the docs for [`ARB_shadow`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_shadow.txt) and they hint that OpenGL is free to implement PCF (Percentage Closer Filtering) in the texture samplers but they can't talk about it in the spec.

First they say:

> - How is bilinear or trilinear filtering implemented?
>
> RESOLUTION: We suggest an implementation behaviour but leave the
>   details up to the implementation.  Differences here amount to the
>   quality and softness of shadow edges.  Specific filtering algorithms
>   could be expressed via layered extensions.  We're intentionally vague
>   here to avoid IP and patent issues.

Then later on:

> If TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER is not NEAREST or TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER is not
>   NEAREST or NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST then r may be computed by comparing
>   more than one depth texture value to the texture R coordinate.  The
>   details of this are implementation-dependent but r should be a value
>   in the range [0, 1] which is proportional to the number of comparison
>   passes or failures.

And ... *that's PCF*!

### Questions

The first question is: Does it work? How many vendors really do PCF when you sample a depth texture with a LINEAR filter?

The second (and most important) question is: How would you detect if hardware PCF filtering via ARB_shadow will work? I want to fall back to a software PCF in the shader if it's not present.

### Notes

- I noticed that ARB_shadow goes hand-in-hand with [`ARB_fragment_program_shadow`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_fragment_program_shadow.txt) (at least on the graphics cards I have access to). ARB_fragment_program_shadow is the low level hardware support for PCF in shaders. Is that a clue to the answer, ie. if both extensions are present then hardware PCF will appear when I say the magic words?
- Implementing ARB_shadow with a simple binary result would be silly. I'd assume the whole point of implementing ARB_shadow in a driver would be to do PCF, even if the docs aren't allowed to say so. Does the mere presence of ARB_shadow imply hardware PCF?